# Populate listbox/select with results from jQuery autocomplete

Tags: jquery, autocomplete

I am trying to populate a select or listbox control from the results in jQuery autocomplete plugin. I do not want to display the div below the autocomplete control when the results are returned. Any help?

---

**UPDATE**:
Here's the code I am trying to populate the listbox:

```
formatItem: function (data) {
    $('#lstBox').append($("<option/>"), {
        value: data.Name,
        text: data.Name
    });
    return '';
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Supposing you are using this [plug in](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Autocomplete), have you tried:

```
$('input#suggest').setOptions({
 max: 0
});
```

if that does not work try:

```
$('input#suggest').setOptions({
 scrollHeight: 0
});
```

Comment: scrollHeight: 0 works. However, there is a thin line below the autocomplete control which does not looks good. Any way to eradicate it. Also I tried to populate the listbox as:

$('#lstBox').append($("<option/>"), {value:data.Name, text: data.Name}); and it does not seems to work.

Comment: you can take away the line by editing the autocomplete css, if you need help with another part of the code please post the complete code in the question